# MQTT Eclipse Paho Android App basic

Tags: android, eclipse, message, mqtt, paho

I am a beginner on **android and MQTT**. I have been trying to figure out how to make an app which send simple messages to the MQTT server(broker). I cant find any simple explanation. Even the sample apps are too complicated to grasp. I know I need the server address, host, client id, user id and password to connect but the question is HOW? Any help will be great, please just try to keep it simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work this way, you need to try to implement this yourself then comeback when it doesn't work, provided the code you have written and a good description of what doesn't work and somebody will help you fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here is some tips to make your own mqtt service if you still have a question for this.

**1. Server Application - mosquitto**

Visit the [site](https://mosquitto.org/download/) to get a binary or source code.
then build or install the mosquitto server for your operating system.

**2. Running and testing the mosquitto broker.**

- Run the mosquitto broker server using command for example,

> mosquitto -c $MOSQUITTO_HOME/conf/mosquitto.conf -d > $MOSQUITTO_HOME/log/mosquitto.log

- Test it with the mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub executable in the bin directory where you installed the mosquitto broker.
  my case is here,

> mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t /test/1
>   mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 -t /test/1 -m "Hello Mosquitt"

**3. Paho java client - mqtt client**

You can use mqtt clients for the [site list](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/downloads.php) using any programming language you are familiar with.

I think you can use java client and android service is the best choice.

The java client might be needed for debugging and the core library.

you can choose either a jframe implementation for the standare jdk or 
swt-plugin implementation for eclipse ide from the [github](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java).

You can also check my customized jframe version of [mine](https://github.com/tommybee-dev/tls-paho-mosquitto). 
it might be helpful how mqtt message can be published 
and subscribed by the broker.

**4. Paho client for android**

Get a source code from [github](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android). 
Be sure to have the core library from the java client library at the step 3.
You can use pre-compiled version of this core library from my [github](https://github.com/tommybee-dev/tls-paho-mosquitto-android/blob/master/screenshot/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.1.jar).
Then, compile and build app with whatever ide tools like eclipse+ADT 
or android studio(recommended)

You can check the images since successfully installed the paho app 
and can also refer my customized android app version from [github](https://github.com/tommybee-dev/tls-paho-mosquitto-android).